# Using different settings locally versus remotely in files such as application.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

In my app I have some code that changes when running locally versus in development on the remote server, such as app_domain in application.yml, etc. Besides having to manually change them each time I run locally versus deploy to remote machine, is there a better way of managing this?

Comment: One approach is to ignore actual application.yml from version control and use application.yml.example and commit changes to it. Copy over the example and modify it on systems. You would still need to edit manually if you add/remove config keys though.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the .yml part. I changed my answer so hopefully it gives you some better ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - for yml

It depends a bit on how you are loading the application.yml but generally when you load yml files ruby parses it all into a hash for you. Thus you can set something up like the database.yml and structure all the yml under your different environments:

```
development:
    domain: localhost

production:
    domain: mydomain.com

test:
    domain: foo
```

and then when you load your yml file you want to grab the settings for the specific environment you are in, like this:

```
MY_CONFIGS = YAML.load_file("[path to my yaml file]/application.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

Comment: I'm talking about application.yml, not .rb.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I like Matthew's answer unless you have some secrets in those files (passwords).

If you have passwords you don't want in source, what I tell my UrbanDeploy customers when they have this type of scenario is to use a script (or we have a built-in script) that effectively does a token replace based on environment. Where the replacements are coming from the deployment system, or a magic file somewhere on the deployment target.

Either way, treat an environment as a first order thing that has data about it that needs to be managed.

Answer (score 0):

Using kwateeSDCM you can customize any file at deployment time on a server by server basis. This way you only need one templatized application.xml and parametrize it depending on the target server.